# accessing array and objects

Tags: arrays, codeigniter, object, foreach

I have a problem with printing my data. In my program, i get the data which was in object and put in an array. say array1[$id] = dataobject. the whole array1 then will be put to array2['list'] like array2['list'] = array1;

the problem is how do i get the data such as the id, name and description.. here's the print_r of the whole array:

this is actually the result of the array, i am not sure how to access this. i want to foreach and get the name and print them:

```
Array ( 
[list] => Array ( 
    [0] => Array ( 
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 1 
            [name] => harry potter 4 
            [description] => harry potter and the goblet of fire book by j.k. rowling 
            [unit_price] => 300.99 
        ) 
    ) 
    [1] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object ( 
            [id] => 4
            [name] => lipton tea
            [description] => yellow label tea
            [unit_price] => 15.00 
        ) 
    ) 
    [2] => Array (
        [0] => stdClass Object (
            [id] => 9
            [name] => tisyu
            [description] => tissue twenty pieces
            [unit_price] => 20.00
        ) 
    )

) 

)
```

Comment: Please read a PHP tutorial. Stack Overflow is for canonical answers to common problems, not for introductory lessons on fundamental syntax.

Comment: Please chill out, meager.  He asked for help.  _That's_ what StackOverflow is for.  No matter how remedial the problem.

Comment: Thanks nicholas roge! i was really desperate this morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would have to access them something like the following:

```
foreach($array['list'] as $array_item){
    $object = $array_item[0];

    echo $object->id."<br />";
    echo $object->name."<br />";
    echo $object->description."<br />";
    echo $object->unit_price."<br />";
}
```

This would yield:

```
1
harry potter 4
harry potter and the goblet of fire book by j.k. rowling
300.99
4
lipton tea
yellow label tea
15.00
9
tisyu
tussue twenty pieces
20.00
```

You can access an objects properties using the -> operator, followed by the property you wish to access.

Comment: Any time.  If you need any more help, feel free to private message me.

Comment: hi nicholas, would like to send you a message but i really cant figure out how to send personal message. i looked for a send message or anything like that in your profile but there is none. i have a question about codeigniter and im afraid some people might find it too shallow again to ask here in stackoverflow. thanks!

Comment: Actually, that's my fault.  Ha ha.  I thought Stack Overflow had a PM system.  If you would like you can e-mail me at the e-mail given in my bio.

Comment: ohhh. that's great! i'm a newbie programmer/webdeveloper. i already solved the problem i had earlier, will email you next time. thanks a bunch nicholas! really glad to bump a nice programmer here! :)

Comment: No problem.  I know this expression is overused, but here's me using it anyways:  Everyone is new at some point.  Just keep at it!  Also never forget (because a lot of people do), Google is your best friend.

Comment: hi nicholas, can't see you email as well! :D

Comment: Ah, that's strange.  You can e-mail me at NicholasRoge [a t] gmail [d o t] com.